# Redis Lettuce: Sending Custom Commands

Tags: java, redis

I'm using [tile38.com](http://tile38.com) with [lettuce.io](https://lettuce.io) on Java. I'm trying to send a custom `NEARBY fleet FENCE POINT 33.462 -112.268 6000` command as per the docs [enter link description here](http://tile38.com/topics/geofencing/), but I don't know how to.

I've been using the `CommandType` in Lettuce, but I can't find a way of sending a `NEARBY`. Does someone know how I could do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have multiple options to send custom commands:

### Custom Commands

With custom commands, you basically define a type implementing the `ProtocolKeyword` interface which helps you as a single point of reference for all your keywords involved in your commands. You can use synchronous, asynchronous, or reactive APIs to invoke the command:

```
enum MyKeywords implements ProtocolKeyword {
    NEARBY, FENCE, POINT;

    private final byte name[];

    MyKeywords() {
        // cache the bytes for the command name. Reduces memory and cpu pressure when using commands.
        name = name().getBytes();
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBytes() {
        return name;
    }
}

CommandArgs<String, String> args = new CommandArgs<>(codec).addKey(key).add(MyKeywords.FENCE).add("POINT").add(lon).add(lat)
List<Object> response = connection.sync().dispatch(MyCommands.FENCE, new NestedMultiOutput<>(codec), args);
```

### Command Interfaces

Command interfaces provide you a higher level of abstraction by declaring command methods on a Java interface. It's declared by a method signature that matches your command to invoke and less verbose than custom commands:

```
interface Tile38 {

  @Command("NEARBY ?0 FENCE POINT ?1 ?2")
  List<Object> nearByFence(String key, double lon, double lat);
}

RedisClient client = …
RedisCommandFactory factory = new RedisCommandFactory(client.connect());
Tile38 commands = factory.getCommands(Tile38.class);
```

Please note that I'm not familiar with Tile38 command responses. Therefore, all code uses `List<Object>` which is the most generic return type.

### See also

- [Lettuce Documentation: Custom Commands](https://lettuce.io/core/release/reference/#_custom_commands).
- [Lettuce Documentation: Command Interfaces](https://lettuce.io/core/release/reference/#redis-command-interfaces).
- [Lettuce JavaDoc: `BaseRedisCommands.dispatch(…)`](https://lettuce.io/lettuce-4/release/api/com/lambdaworks/redis/api/sync/BaseRedisCommands.html#dispatch-com.lambdaworks.redis.protocol.ProtocolKeyword-com.lambdaworks.redis.output.CommandOutput-com.lambdaworks.redis.protocol.CommandArgs-).
- [Lettuce JavaDoc: `CommandOutput`](https://lettuce.io/lettuce-4/release/api/com/lambdaworks/redis/output/CommandOutput.html).