# calling a Redis function(loaded Lua script) using Lettuce library

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, lua, lettuce

I am using `Java`, `Spring-Boot`, `Redis 7.0.4`, and `lettuce 6.2.0.RELEASE`.

I wrote a `Lua` script as below:

```
#!lua
name = updateRegisterUserJobAndForwardMsg
function updateRegisterUserJobAndForwardMsg (KEYS, ARGV)
  local jobsKey = KEYS[1]
  local inboxKey = KEYS[2]
  local jobRef = KEYS[3]
  local jobIdentity  = KEYS[4]
  local accountsMsg = ARGV[1]
  
  local jobDetail = redis.call('HGET', jobsKey ,jobRef)
  local jobObj = cmsgpack.unpack(jobDetail)
  local msgSteps = jobObj['steps']
  msgSteps[jobIdentity] = 'IN_PROGRESS'
  
  jobDetail = redis.call('HSET', jobsKey, jobRef, cmsgpack.pack(jobObj))
  
  local ssoMsg = redis.call('RPUSH', inboxKey, cmsgpack.pack(accountsMsg))

  return jobDetail
end
redis.register_function('updateRegisterUserJobAndForwardMsg', updateRegisterUserJobAndForwardMsg)
```

Then I registered it as a function in my `Redis` using the below command:

```
cat updateJobAndForwardMsgScript.lua | redis-cli -x FUNCTION LOAD REPLACE
```

Now I can easily call my function using `Redis-cli` as below:

```
 FCALL updateJobAndForwardMsg 4 key1 key2 key3 key4 arg1
```

And it will get executed successfully!!

Now I want to call my function using `lettuce` which is my `Redis-client` library in my application, but I haven't found anything on the net, and it seems that `lettuce` does not support `Redis 7 new feature` for calling `FUNCTION` using `FCALL` command!!

Does it have any other customized way for executing Redis commands using lettuce?

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more research about the requirement, I found the following StackOverFlow answer:

[StackOverFlow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48589406/7189597)

And also based on the documentation:

[Redis Custom Commands :](https://lettuce.io/core/release/reference/#_custom_commands)

> Custom commands can be dispatched on the one hand using Lua and the
> eval() command, on the other side Lettuce 4.x allows you to trigger
> own commands. That API is used by Lettuce itself to dispatch commands
> and requires some knowledge of how commands are constructed and
> dispatched within Lettuce.
>
> Lettuce provides two levels of command dispatching:
>
> - Using the synchronous, asynchronous or reactive API wrappers which
>   invoke commands according to their nature
> - Using the bare connection to influence the command nature and
>   synchronization (advanced)

So I could handle my requirements by creating an `interface` which `extends` the `io.lettuce.core.dynamic.Commands` `interface` as below:

```
public interface CustomCommands extends Commands {

    @Command("FCALL :funcName :keyCnt :jobsKey :inboxRef :jobsRef :jobIdentity :frwrdMsg ")
    Object fcall_responseJob(@Param("funcName") byte[] functionName, @Param("keyCnt") Integer keysCount,
                 @Param("jobsKey") byte[] jobsKey, @Param("inboxRef") byte[] inboxRef,
                 @Param("jobsRef") byte[] jobsRef, @Param("jobIdentity") byte[] jobIdentity,
                 @Param("frwrdMsg") byte[] frwrdMsg);

}
```

Then I could easily call my loaded `FUNCTION`(which was a Lua script) as below:

```
private void updateResponseJobAndForwardMsgToSSO(SharedObject message, SharedObject responseMessage) {
        try {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new MessagePackMapper();
            RedisCommandFactory factory = new RedisCommandFactory(connection);
            CustomCommands commands = factory.getCommands(CustomCommands.class);
            Object obj = commands.fcall_responseJob(
                    Constant.REDIS_RESPONSE_JOB_FUNCTION_NAME.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
                    Constant.REDIS_RESPONSE_JOB_FUNCTION_KEY_COUNT,
                    (message.getAgent() + Constant.AGENTS_JOBS_POSTFIX).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
                    (message.getAgent() + Constant.AGENTS_INBOX_POSTFIX).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
                    message.getReferenceNumber().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
                    message.getTyp().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
                    objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(responseMessage));
            LOG.info(obj.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```